# How to update the layout inside a function in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, user-experience

### Problem

We have a `FloatLayout` that gets some widgets and loses some (using `add_widget` and `remove_widget`) inside a function.The problem is the window gets updated when the function reaches its end. Then Kivy updates the window and user only sees the last results.

How to update the window when we are inside a function so user can see results ???

### What i tried

I tried `do_layout` and `_trigger_layout` (read that somewhere on SO). None of them did the job (no traceback, no warning, literally no change)

Also read Kivy documentation but nothing was helpful there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making all your changes while blocking the gui, use Clock.schedule_interval or Clock.schedule_once to let Kivy go back to rendering in between each change.

Edit: Also to be clear, your problem is not that you have failed to update the layout, but that you haven't given Kivy any opportunity to render the changes.

Comment: could you just write a small snippet to improve your answer quality.

Comment: @000Zer000 Check out the kivy docs: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html#adding-ball-animation

Comment: Thanks @daawx. But i knew how to do that i was just telling him to improve the quality of his answer